# RCSwitch for Alarm System

Tags: arduino-mega

Folks,

I use the RCSwitch sketch to notify my WiFi alarm controller when a motion is detected.

Using the Receiver Code, I have got the following information related to the motion detection signal from the PIR (detector):

```
Decimal: 8876073 (24Bit) 
Binary: 100001110111000000101001 
Tri-State: not applicable 
PulseLength: 311 microseconds 
Protocol: 1
Raw data: 9700,1096,264,400,952,420,964,380,968,372,1012,1040,316,1028,324,1016,380,332,1008,1012,340,1040,344,1000,348,356,1024,324,1016,332,1012,372,1016,336,1012,372,1008,1016,336,328,1016,1008,380,324,1016,368,1012,1008,344,
```

My Transmitter Sketch is as follows:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 // Transmitter is connected to Arduino Pin #10 
 mySwitch.enableTransmit(10);
 // Optional set pulse length.
 mySwitch.setPulseLength(312);
 // set protocol (default is 1, will work for most outlets)
 // mySwitch.setProtocol(2);
 // Optional set number of transmission repetitions.
 mySwitch.setRepeatTransmit(5);
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
 mySwitch.send("100001110111000000101001");//Detection Signal
 //mySwitch.send("100001110111000000101001");//Detection Signal
 //mySwitch.send("101110100000000011000010");//Panic Signal
 //mySwitch.send("101110100000000011000010");//Panic Signal
 Serial.print("Sent 100001110111000000101001 ");
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
 delay(500);
 digitalWrite(13,LOW);
 delay(10000); 
}
```

While it appears the message is being sent, unfortunately my Alarm Control doesn't detect it.

Can anyone suggest a fix please?

Ranjith

Comment: why do you expect the alarm control to accept communication from the arduino? ... it seems that it would be a security failure if the code was accepted

Comment: I need to replace the unreliable wireless alarm system with a new wired system which I have built using good components. However, I also need to use the old wireless security controller to take the advantage of the wireless notification function of it. Given that none of the detectors communicates to the security controller, the security of the system will not be compromised.